# String and Numeric Literals in Date and Time Context

Tags: mysql

MySql [states](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) the following about date:

> As a number in either YYYYMMDD or YYMMDD format, provided that the
>   number makes sense as a date. For example, 19830905 and 830905 are
>   interpreted as '1983-09-05'.

So I tried:

`select date 19830905;`

output: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '19830905' at line 1`

How do I go about using this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the very same page you are quoting from, it says a bit further up:

> **Standard SQL and ODBC Date and Time Literals.** Standard SQL permits temporal literals to be specified using a type keyword and a string. The space between the keyword and string is optional.
>   `DATE 'str'`
>   `TIME 'str'`
>   `TIMESTAMP 'str'`

So MySQL apparently allows `SELECT DATE '19830905'` to follow standard SQL – but using a numeric date value at this point simply seems not supported.

In other contexts however they work fine, such as f.e.

```
SELECT 19830905 + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

(Result: `1983-09-06`)

---

(What you quoted, is under the headline **String and Numeric Literals in Date and Time Context**. One could perhaps argue that *by definition* the case in question is not such a context, as it is explicitly defined differently, to accept a string literal only.)

Comment: So do these keywords (date, time, timestamp) act like type casting?

Comment: Hm, not really, I think – “temporal literals” is what the manual calls it in the quote above, and that just seems to be a syntax construct on its own …